# Disable row selection in existing jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid version 4.4.4 and i have an existing populated jqgrid table where i would like to disable a row when a user select a specific value in an external dropdown menu. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5DrU.jpg)

[image]

For example, as the image show, if the user select the value 1 i would like that all rows with different ID (0 and 2) contained in the table become unselectable. In the same way when 0 value is selected, row 1 and 2 will be unselected and so on.

I would like to do this without using gridUnload method.

Now i have found the way to disable the input button but a user can push on the row anyway and select the value.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to describe your problem more exactly. You wrote currently about "change few attributes". What you mean under "attribute"? Do you mean the options of jqGrid? Some options are changeable dynamically another one unchangable. Thus you should specify exactly what you need to implement. Another example: you write about "dropdown menu". Do you mean some *external menu* outside of jqGrid or you mean dropdown from the filter toolbar or editing field (in case of usage inline editing, cell editing or form editing) or a filed of the searching dialog of jqGrid?

Comment: Including of JavaScript code, which you use or some pictures would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I rewrite the post...

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid allows your to define `beforeSelectRow` callback, which will be called **before** the new row will be selected. The callback get the `rowid` of the currently selecting row as the parameter. The callback can get the value of selected item in the external dropdown first and then return `true` or `false` based on the selected value and the `rowid` of selecting row. In the way you can implement your requirements.

Additionally you can use `getGridParam` method with the parameter `"selarrrow"` to get the array with the list of rowids of all currently selected rows. You can change the current selection on jqGrid after the user changes the selection in the external dropdown. You can use `setSelection` method to toggle the selection of specific row.

You can implement additionally `onSelectAll` callback, which will be called if the user click on the column header of multiselect column to select or deselect all rows. You can toggle selection of some rows to hold the rule which you want to follow.

I'd recommend you to consider to use `height: "auto"` option of jqGrid to improve the look of the grid. Additionally I'd recommend you to upgrade from the retro version 4.4.4 to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.4. You can use if from CDN directly (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) or download it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid) or from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid). The version 4.4.4 is dead and it's not more supported.